# python (django) regex limit result not working

Tags: python, regex, django

The spec is all characters except white-space and capitalized characters.

Here is the regex validator on the model:

```
path = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="/blog/posts/...", unique=True, validators=[
        RegexValidator(regex='(^[a-z0-9-:!@#$%^&*(){}\\?<>,.;\'"`~|/]+){1}', message="Lowercase with no whitespace allowed")
    ])
```

Here is the unit test:

```
def test_path_regex(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        post = Post(title="bad regex", path="Super-2Test-2", slug="special")
        if post.full_clean():
            post.save()

    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        post = Post(title="bad regex", path="super-2test 2", slug="special")
        if post.full_clean():
            post.save()

    self.assertEqual(Post.objects.filter(title="bad regex").count(), 0)
```

Result:

```
line 27, in test_path_regex
    post.save()
AssertionError: ValidationError not raised

FAILED (failures=1)
```

the reason for this seems to be that the `RegexValidator` is not flagging text if it can match part of the string and `{1}` is not helping. As you can see from this link: [http://pythex.org/](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5E%5Ba-z0-9-%3A!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%7B%7D%5C%5C%3F%3C%3E%2C.%3B%5C%27%22%60~%7C%2F%5D%2B)%7B1%7D&test_string=super-2test%202&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: To match whole string, you need `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Try `regex=r'^[a-z0-9-:!@#$%^&*(){}\\?<>,.;\'"\`~|/]+$'`

Comment: Thanks, Can't believe I missed that. Post as answer if you want. I'll approve and upvote as soon as the system lets me

Comment: _The spec is all characters except white-space and capitalized characters._ Then why not use `[^\sA-Z]` ?

Comment: Actually, I used `r''` in the suggestion - did you intend to match  a backslash with ``\\``?

Comment: @Rahul thanks. `regex='^[^\sA-Z]+$'` works!

Comment: @MHornbacher: Great !

Comment: @Rahul: Please post your answer.

Comment: @MHornbacher: The `{1}` makes no difference if used outside a character class (or it "ruins" a character class if used inside it since each char inside is matched individually): every atom matches a single occurrence if not quantified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The spec is all characters except white-space and capitalized characters.

You can simply use [Negated Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). In your case it will be `[^\sA-Z]`. This will match all characters except `whitespace` and `Upper Case alphabets`